# Adding 2 lights, white wires only?

Tags: electrical, attic

I am adding 2 additional light receptacles in my garage attic.   I thought this was going to be pretty straightforward until I got to the currently working light in the attic (pic attached).   I get white wire to white wire and black wire to black wire but how do I attach 2 new lights (black, white, and ground wires) to this configuration?

There is a single switch next to the attic door. I've attached pics in the link below.

Comment: You connect the whites to the whites and blacks to the blacks?  Is there some other point of confusion?  Oh, and the picture doesn't look like it worked.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6lpJwdT36NGckxPMWhieXRvUjA&usp=sharing

Comment: when I took off the light from the box I found that 2 whites were connected to the existing light fixture.   I'm a rookie but I thought it should have 1 white and 1 black connected.   1)  Need to know if I should correct this.  2) if not, how do I connect the other 2 lights to this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The picture helps a lot.  The second white wire is coming from the switch, and it *should* have been wrapped with black electrical tape to indicate it was actually playing the role of a black wire.  Determine which white comes from the switch, and that's the "black" wire.

Then the problem is as simple as connecting the new whites to the white wire, and new blacks to the black.

The following picture is what you have except on the light side, they have connected the black wires together and both whites are going to the lamp.

[image: Black coded white wire]

In order to determine which wire goes to the switch, you'll need a voltage tester.  Turn off the breaker to the circuit and the light switch, and carefully remove the wire nut from the black wires in the lamp box.  Be sure the wires are not touching anything, and turn the breaker back on.  Using your voltage meter, touch the twisted black wires with one probe and each white wire going to the lamp.  The white wire that shows 120v is the actual white wire coming from the breaker box.  The other white wire will be the "black" wire coming from the switch.  Turn the breaker back off and twist the wire nut back on.  Be super careful when measuring the voltage with the breaker on.

Comment: getting close...thank you.   When you're indicating the 2nd white wire are you referring to the one that is on the brass screw?

Comment: @kentjacobson Does the diagram help?  I don't see any brass screws in your pictures, but the white wire coming from the switch is acting as a black wire, so it should go to the brass screw.

Comment: @Kentjacobson - What you have is a switched loop that was not marked.  Power goes in at the light socked, the hot is redirected to the switch (neutrals stay in the light outlet) and a switched hot is returned back to the light outlet to control the light.

Comment: not sure why they configured it this way but I think I can handle it from here.

Comment: Well, to be clear, the only thing they did wrong was not "coding" the white wires with black tape.  This is the _right_ way to do it.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6lpJwdT36NGazZ2S3IxRHQ1SjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yep, makes sense.  Just make sure you trace the wire back to the switch so you know for sure which white wire is the "black".

Comment: great, thanks for your help!   great site and it's cool to know there are people out here willing to help!

Comment: Last obvious question....how do I "Just make sure you trace the wire back to the switch so you know for sure which white wire is the "black""

Comment: when I touch the black and white wires of the new light to the screws on the old light receptacle I get a working new light.  then I can switch the black  and white wires and put them on the opposite screws on the old light and I still get a working new light.  What's the risk in not knowing which white wire is "black" on the old light?

Comment: For a simple ceramic light socket, there's really no risk.  For something in a metal housing, there's a chance of problems, and for electrical outlets, you always want to be very sure.

Comment: @kentjacobson if you switch the polarity the risk is a shock hazard when removing a broken bulb and the switch is not off.  The outer ring should be neutral and the inner nub hot.  You can always use a volt meter or a non-contact current tester to find which wire is hot (please mark it with black tape).

Comment: appreciate the help everyone!.  Lights are safely working!

Comment: @kentjacobson, don't forget to mark the answer as correct.